# How to use Scroll top method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The header on scroll should slide/up down as indicated in the jQuery, However, in mobile iOS this does not occur and the header judders at the top of the screen?

This works on Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Internet Explorer and Safari - on big browsers.

Is this occurring because of an incorrect use of the scroll top method? How do I correct this?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scrollTop(0);

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var header = $('header');
    var content = $('content');
    var headerBg = $('.header-bg');
    var headerCnt = $('.header-content');
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var dynHeaderVisible = false;
  
    if (lastScrollTop > scrollTop) {
      if (scrollTop <= 400) {
        headerBg.css("height", 0);
        headerCnt.css('color', 'white');
      } else {
        headerBg.css("height", 80);
        headerCnt.css("height", 80);
        headerCnt.css('color', 'black');
      }
    } else {
      // Down
      if (scrollTop > 350) {
        console.log ("hi");
        headerCnt.css("height", 0);
        headerBg.css("height", 0);
      }
    }
    
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
});

$.fn.isOnScreen = function(){
    var element = this.get(0);
    var bounds = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return bounds.top < window.innerHeight && bounds.bottom > 0;
}
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:1em;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
  }
 a {
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
    letter-spacing:0.15em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    transition: .3s color;
 transition: .3s height;
 }


header {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

header ul {
  z-index: 20;
}

.header-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.header-bg,
.header-content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-bg {
  z-index: 100;
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  transition: .3s height;
  height: 0;
}

.header-content {
  z-index: 200;
  transition: .3s color;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 80px;
  transition: .3s height;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 47%;
 color: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size:.8em;
    letter-spacing:0.05em;
 transition: .3s color;
 }
</style>
<style>

content {
  display: block;
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.stage {
    color: #fff;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: white;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 48px;
 height: 200px;
 width: 100%;
}

.stage-0 {
    background: grey;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src= "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="header-bg"></div>
    <div class="header-content">
      <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="" class="logo">Logo </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<content>
<div class="stage stage-0">1</div>
<div class="stage stage-2">3</div>
<div class="stage stage-4">5</div>
<div class="stage stage-6">7</div>
<div class="stage stage-8">9</div>
<div class="stage stage-10">11</div>
<div class="stage stage-12">13</div>
<div class="stage stage-14">15</div>
<div class="stage stage-16">17</div>
<div class="stage stage-18">19</div>
<div class="stage stage-20">21</div>
<div class="stage stage-22">23</div>
</content>
```

Comment: Try lowering the scrollTop height to see if that changes anything, had a similar problem like this once and I believe it was caused by the screen not being 'high' enough which made it stutter

Comment: In the jquery code you provided. scrollTop <= 400 etc. try lowering all those heights

Comment: Adjusting those heights does not solve this issue...

Comment: I see no issue. What iOS version are you using?

Comment: iOS 9.2 - the header will not drop and judders & iOS7.1.2 - the header will not drop

Comment: Just enable WebInspector in your iPhone/iPod/iPad settings, connect it via cable to Mac and try to debug it remotly. This is the best option

Comment: I'm previewing in adobe dreamweaver cc. This is my first site and am teaching myself as I go. I have no idea where/how to start looking for this error... any tips or resources you recommend?

Comment: I wish I could help but I am confused, what you are trying to do.

Comment: Does this always happen or only when there isn't 'enough' content in the body? For example try adding more content to it and see if it still stutters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(), //Get the current vertical position of the scroll bar for the first element in the set of matched elements
                     header = $('.header-content'); // Target Element

    if(scrollTop > header.offset().top) {
        header.addClass('navbar-fixed-top'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not fix the issue? can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed elements can have some pretty wonky effects on mobile devices due to it not working properly with touch events (in this case the scrolling I guess).

I'm not 100% if that's the issue here but I think there's a good possibility that it is.

There's something called Modernizr (https://modernizr.com/) which helps you detect all kinds browser-related stuff including if it's working on a touchscreen or not. I don't think there's currently a real solution to the bad working between touch events and fixed elements, but with Modernizr you can try to find some kind of workaround.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you have some nested `position:fixed` elements inside other `position: fixed` elements. This can sometimes cause weird bugs on mobiles, in my experience.

So try replacing the `position:fixed` line from this rule:

```
.header-bg,
.header-content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

with `position: absolute`

```
.header-bg,
.header-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Nothing execute during scrolling on mobile safari.** You can simply put a gif in your page and you can see even this gif image stopped animating during scrolling.

On mobile safari, the 'scroll' event only fires once after window stopped scrolling. If you really need to monitoring scroll event and do certain things according scrolltop in real time. You need some third party lib such as [IScroll in github](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll).

It used 'translate' to simulate 'scroll' effect.